# How to get back the dangling objects

Tags: serialization, flatbuffers

I am working in a project with large data that needs to partition the FlatBuffers into many smaller pieces. I am encountering some cases like this.

Schema:

```
table A {
  number: int;
}
table B {
  a: [A];
}

root_type B
```

Code:

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;
int num0 = 3;
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 5;
int num3 = 7;
auto a0 = CreateA(builder, num0);
auto a1 = CreateA(builder, num1);
auto a2 = CreateA(builder, num2);
auto a3 = CreateA(builder, num3);

std::vector<flatbuffers::Offset<A>> A_vector;
A_vector.push_back(a0);
A_vector.push_back(a1);

auto B = builder.CreateVector(A_vector);
auto orc = CreateB(builder, B);
builder.Finish(orc);
```

If I can not push_back a2 and a3 into `A_vector` for some reasons, will a2 and a3 also be serialized in this case? How can I get a2 and a3 back after serialization via `builder.GetBufferPointer()`?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please STOP adding Flatbuffers back into the title. You've already tagged the question with that information; it is NOT necessary to repeat it again in the title. The tag system here works extremely well and does not need you  to add noise to the title to help it.

Answer (score 0):

If you serialize an object in a FlatBuffer and don't store its offset anywhere, there is no way to access it. You need to serialize it into a different FlatBufferBuilder instance.

Comment: I check the size of Flatbuffer via builder.GetSize(). The size still become larger even if I only create a2 and a3 but don't store their offset. So, there is no way to access a2 and a3 but they are still serialized into disk. Is that correct?